# Problems pasting values on another workbook sheet on vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have the following code in order to copy a sheet from a workbook and paste it on the sheet 1 of another workbook called "Control_de_precios":

```
Sub createSpreadSheet()

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
    .Title = "Control_precios_ddmmaaaa"
    .Subject = "Control_de_precios"
    .SaveAs Filename:="Control_precios_ddmmaaaa.xls"
End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
NewBook.Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get the 438 error because the last instruction, and I don't get to paste values on my new workbook. If I change it for:

`ActiveSheet(1).Paste`

I don't get the 438 error, and I get to paste the formulas, but I want to paste the values.

¿Could anyone help me?

Comment: ActiveSheet(1).Paste works for you? I find that strange, because it seems like mix of "ActiveSheet" and "Sheets(1)". Have you tried removing the "(1)"?

Comment: Yes sorry, my original code has:


`ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub` 

But I still get the 438 error.

Comment: What is the error message for 438?

Comment: "This object does not admit this property or method" I think it refers to the PasteSpecial method.

Comment: Try adding Range reference after the activesheet. When I do it this way it works. ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues.

Comment: It worked, thank you, you can put this as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Range reference after the activesheet. When I do it this way it works. `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

instaed of

```
ActiveSheet(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```